# I want data in the rest of wpf DataGrid to be read only and only new row should be editable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have managed to get `DataGrid` to show new row for adding new item.
Problem i face now is i want data in the rest of wpf `DataGrid` to be read only and only new row should be editable.

Currently this is how my `DataGrid` looks.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGridTest" CanUserAddRows="True" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TestBinding}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>        
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Test1}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Test2}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>               
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But since I have kept the columns read only, a new row also adds as read only which is what I don't want.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this [MSDN blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/46463fc9-fda6-4bf0-80f6-cd1e66f45690/)

Also, try the following example:

Xaml:

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGridTest" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TestBinding}" Margin="0,50,0,0" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Test1}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Test2}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Add new row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

CS:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new Test { Test1 = "Test1", Test2 = "Test2" };

        DataGridTest.Items.Add(data);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: At least in this simple example, you could simplify things a bit and not declare the Test class at all. Anonymous type instead: `DataGridTest.Items.Add(new { Test1 = "Test1", Test2 = "Test2" });`

Comment: i'm using the same method but after certain rows it show null reference error

Comment: @Dave Clemmer ., How can I do this in the ViewModel.

Comment: One big problem with this solution is that `DataGridColumn`'s `IsReadOnly` property is *not bidnable*, contrary to the IsReadOnly of DataGrid itself.

Answer (score 19):

Just simply use this `Style` of `DataGridRow`:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsNewItem,Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Clear and concise, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz that is what the OP wanted