# DataGrid no means of adding rows?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

In VS 2019, there seems to be no way of adding rows to a DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="myDataGrid" Background="#50000000" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding myDataGRid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" />

myDataGrid.Rows.Add(r); // <= DataGrid does not contain a definition for 'Rows' ...
```

How can I add rows/columns to a DataGrid programmatically?

The table can added by columns, but this is clunky when adding new rows (column contents have to be saved, column sizes increased by 1 and refiled with previous values).

This question does not appear to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251327) one because:

- in the linked to example the grid already has a fixed structure that can be populated with a number of items
- in this case, however, the DataGrid layout is unknown and created upon parsing a .tex file (no. of cols/rows can vary from one file to another)

Comment: _"In VS 2019, there seems to be no way of adding rows to a DataGrid"_ - That's not an issue of VS 2019, though.

Comment: @Sinatr Partially, the answers there imply that the DataGrid layout is fixed in terms of no. of rows/cols. In my case, I don't know the layout of the tables (it's generated based on a .tex file).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding rows to DataGrid directly, you should modify its data source. DataGrid will reflect any changes you make in data source, e.g. adding a new row. As mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netcore-3.1#binding-to-data):

> To bind the `DataGrid` to data, set the `ItemsSource` property to an
> `IEnumerable` implementation.

`Columns` property can be modified programmatically:

> You can use the `Columns` collection to programmatically add, insert,
> remove, and change any columns in the control at run time. Check the
> `IsAutoGenerated` property to determine whether a column is auto
> generated or user defined. Auto-generated columns will be
> automatically added, removed, or regenerated when the `ItemsSource`
> changes.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any code that sheds some light on how programmatic creation/removal of rows/cols can be done? In my case I cannot bind a row to an object as the user may automatically add new columns.

Comment: Sure. You must add items to your list or collection, not to your DataGrid. The Binding is already done with ItemsSource Databinding

Comment: @sven Can you point to a more specific reference (code)? If row 1 has 4 items and row 2, 6 how can I get the max size per row and update the UI accordingly?

Comment: I think with my Example and the tip from Miamy you can do it.

Comment: @Sebi, `DataGrid` is designed to show the homogeneous data structures, such as list of orders. In your case I'm not sure this component is the proper choice. I think you can try implement the required functionality with a `Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel :

```
....
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
....
    
 public void AddNewCustomer(Customer customer)
 {
   
    Customers.Add(customer);
            
 }
```

xaml file :
...

```
<DataGrid 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}">

...
```

Answer (score 0):

> In VS 2019, there seems to be no way of adding rows to a DataGrid ...

VS 2019 is an IDE and the `DataGrid` class is part of WPF. Anyway, try the `Items` property:

```
myDataGrid.Items.Add(r);
```

But if you want to be able to *edit* the records in the `DataGrid`, you should set the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and add items to this one instead of adding items directly to the `Items` property.